# Extract SVO triples from preprocessed text

Tags: python, syntax, nlp, triples

I need to extract subject-verb-object triples from a Dutch text. The text is analysed by a Dutch NLP tool named [Frog](https://languagemachines.github.io/frog/) which tokenized, parsed, tagged, lemmatized,...it. Frog produces FoLiA XML, or tab-delimited column-formatted output, one line per token. Because of some problems with the XML file, I chose to work with the column format. This example represents one sentence. [image] Now I need to extract per sentence the SVO triples, therefore I need the last column which are the dependency relations. So I need to get the ROOT element and the su and obj1 elements which belong to the ROOT. Unfortunately the example sentence has no obj1. Let's pretend it has. My idea was to first create a nested list with a list per sentence.

```
    import csv
    with open('romanfragment_frogged.tsv','r') as f:
         reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
         tokens = []
         sentences = []
         list_of_sents = []
         for line in reader:
             tokens.append(line)
             #print(tokens)
             for token in tokens:
                 if token == '1':
                    previous_sentence = list_of_sents
                    sentences.append(previous_sentence)
         list_of_sents = []
         list_of_sents.append(tokens)
         print(list_of_sents)
```

When I print 'tokens', I get one list with all the tokens. So that is correct, but I'm still trying to create a nested list with 1 list (of tokens) per sentence.
Can someone help me with this problem?

(P.S. the second problem is that I'm not sure, how to continue once I get a nested list)

Comment: I think, for starters, there is some confusion about the input format. The tool's website you link to says that the output is XML. However, the image and your attempt to split on `"\t"` suggest that it is a TSV (tab-separated plain-text) file. Yet again, you claim that it is a Word document – presumably the old, binary ".doc" version, which would be the worst of all options. Please sort this out and update the question.

Comment: @lenz As the website says there are 2 output options 'Frog produces FoLiA XML, or tab-delimited column-formatted output, one line per token'. Because of some problems with the XML file, I chose to work with the column format. But I saved it as a .doc like you said, is it better to save it as a .txt file?

Comment: Ok, I see – I think you didn't actually save it as a Word document, you just saved it with a file name ending in ".doc". Convention is to use ".tsv" or, sometimes, ".csv".

Comment: The main problem here is that `for line in text` iterates over the characters in the text. Unlike an open file, string objects don't magically split text into lines when iterated over. Best practice is to use `with open(...) as f:`, then inside that block `for line in f:` etc. Also consider using the `csv` library for parsing the TSV file.

Comment: @lenz I analyzed the text again and saved it this time in Frog as a .tsv file. I changed my code and the question above. I managed to get al the lines in one list. But now I don't know how to make the nested list per sentence. I'm new in programming so I still have a lot of problems and questions

Comment: I'd use verb-srl and extract A0-A1:  http://deagol.cs.illinois.edu:8080

Comment: @Daniel Does It work for Dutch? Because the Frog NLP tool is very accurated and especially for Dutch. Furthermore, my University asks to use the Frog NLP tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
def iter_sentences(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
         reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
         sentence = []
         for row in reader:
             if not row:
                # Ignore blank lines.
                continue
             if row[0] == '1' and sentence:
                 # A new sentence started.
                 yield sentence
                 sentence = []
             sentence.append(row)
         # Last sentence.
         if sentence:
             yield sentence

def iter_triples(fn):
    for sentence in iter_sentences(fn):
        # Get all subjects and objects.
        subjects = [tok for tok in sentence if tok[-1] == 'su']
        objects = [tok for tok in sentence if tok[-1] == 'obj1']
        # Now try to map them: find pairs with a head in the same position.
        for obj in objects:
            for subj in subjects:
                # row[-2] is the position of the head.
                if subj[-2] == obj[-2]:
                    # Matching subj-obj pair found.
                    # Now get the verb (the head of both subj and obj).
                    # Its position is given in the second-to-last column.
                    position = int(subj[-2])
                    # Subtract 1, as the positions start counting at 1.
                    verb = sentence[position-1]
                    yield subj, verb, obj

for subj, verb, obj in iter_triples('romanfragment_frogged.tsv'):
    # Only print the surface forms.
    print(subj[1], verb[1], obj[1])
```

Quick explanation:
`iter_sentences` iterates over sentences.
Each sentence is a nested list:
It's a list of tokens, and each token is a list itself (containing the row number, surface form, lemma, POS, dependency etc.).
The `iter_triples` function iterates over triples ‹subject, verb, object›.
Each element of these triples represents a token (ie. a list, again).

The last three lines of code are just an example of how to use the `iter_triples` function.
I don't know how much and which information you need from each triple...

Comment: thank you! But this code `for row in reader:
             if row[0] == '1' and sentence ` gives me an Index error: list index out of range

Comment: Probably a blank line. You can add `if not row: continue` before that check, then blank lines will be skipped.

Comment: indeed, problem solved. I edited your code. Now I still have 2 small questions. 1. I don't fully understand how this line works verb = sentence[int(subj[-2])-1]. 2. I need this to work on different text. The SVO triples serve as a feature for machine learning. Is it possible to get as output from iter_triples a nested list with the triples per sentence, but only the token name and the relation. So element 2 and 10 from the list per token?

Comment: (1) I tried to make that a bit clearer. The second-to-last column is a pointer to the token/line which is the head. We need to type-cast it to an integer and then subtract 1, because Python's lists start at 0, not 1. (2) To get triples per sentences, you could remove the outer `for` loop (= delete the first list) and call the function with a sentence instead of the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the clear up. This is my very last question. Correct me if I'm wrong. I thought the positions which you can read in the second-to-last column started at 0, because the position of the verb, the ROOT is always 0. I also still don't get why we do verb = sentence[...] in that line. I'm still a bit confused about that line of code.

Comment: The numbers in the second-to-last column refer to the numbers you can see in the first column. The root has no head, so there's no line it can point to, which is expressed through "0". – The variable `sentence` is a list of tokens (TSV rows). For example, `sentence[0]` is the line for the token "Marie". This token's head is at position 2, thus we subtract 1 and look for `sentence[1]`, ie. the second line, which represents the token "vroeg".

Comment: Oh, now I fully understand it Thank you for all your help!